# Restrict access to user's data in Spring MongoRepository

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, spring-data-rest

I use Spring Data Rest with Spring Data Mongo.

I have a rather simple REST API which looks similar to this:

```
public class User {
        String id;
        String email;
        String password;
        List<String> roles;
}

public class UserData {
        String data;
        User user;
}

@PreAuthorize("hasRole('ROLE_USER')")
public interface QueryTemplateRepository extends
        MongoRepository<UserData, String> {
}
```

What I want now is that users can only access their data and if they create/edit data it will be linked to their account.

Do I have to get rid of the MongoRepository and write everything myself? Is there some kind of interceptor or filter where I can do this?

I will want to create more REST APIs that are restricted to the user's data, so it would be great if there was some generic solution to this problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can use features of **AbstractMongoEventListener**, it has convinient methods for your needs:

void   onAfterConvert(DBObject dbo, E source)
 void   onAfterSave(E source, DBObject dbo)
 void   onBeforeSave(E source, DBObject dbo)
void    onBeforeConvert(E source)
void    onAfterLoad(DBObject dbo)
 void   onApplicationEvent(MongoMappingEvent event)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is a concern you could deal with in your service layer through aspects as a generic approach. *AbstractMongoEventListener* is a good example of an applied aspect technique.

Because you are dealing with spring-data-rest, no service layer is available unless you wrap it and expose the repository via a Controller.

There is nothing in REST standard regarding allowing modification/deletion of entities only by the creator of it.